# Why does this explicitly-linked DLL delegate succeed in one program but not another?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have 2 programs which share a project in which an API DLL is used to perform actions on files in another directory. The problem that I have is that this code works in one project, but in the other it fails:

```
moduleHandle = LoadLibrary(“api.dll”)
```

Earlier on, the program that fails failed to connect to the API DLL here so after comparing the Process Monitor logs of both I copied some DLLs into the same directory as it. It then succeeded, and the values of moduleHandle are now the same in both programs. Next:

```
methodPointer = GetProcAddress(moduleHandle, "NameOfSomeFunction")
delegateForSomeFunction = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(methodPointer, GetType(SomeFunctionType))
```

When we get to the delegateForSomeFunction, I can see that the value of _methodPtr in them is different from one program to another. Then when we get to invoking the delegate:

```
Dim argsArray() As Object = New Object() {directoryPath, errorFilePath}        
Dim retVal As Short = delegateForSomeFunction.DynamicInvoke(argsArray)
```

In one program this just fails silently. I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed. What should I do to investigate this further and how can I get it to work?

I’m running this on debug in Visual Studio 2013, and the project is in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Although copying the correct versions of dependencies from winsxs into the same directory of the API DLL did allow me to perform LoadLibrary without obvious errors, it caused more errors in the background.

The problem was in the manifest in the end. There was a post-build event that removed the manifest from the .exe in preparation for a deployment step that allowed you to specify different versions of the API present. Creating a proper appname.exe.manifest file specifying the dependent assemblies that I was failing to load normally, and then placing this into the same directory as the .exe, solved the issue.